# How to implement a floating point parser feature in Haskell code for integer processing?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators

Referring to my assignment's description (I'm student with only basic experience in Haskell), I have to make a simple calculator parser utilizing Text.Parsec. So far that program can read some string input to execute parsing through integer values only, for instance:

```
parseTest addition "5 + 8 / 4"
```

There is a complete code of the program I've actually:

```
import Text.Parsec hiding(digit)
import Data.Functor

type CalcParser a = Parsec String () a

digit :: CalcParser Char
digit = oneOf ['0'..'9']

number :: CalcParser Integer
number = read <$> many1 digit

fp_char :: CalcParser String 
fp_char = many1 digit


applyMany :: a -> [a -> a] -> a
applyMany x [] = x
applyMany x (h:t) = applyMany (h x) t


div_ :: CalcParser (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
div_= do
    char '/'
    return div

star :: CalcParser (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
star = do
    char '*'    
    return (*)  

plus :: CalcParser (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
plus = do
    char '+'    
    return (+)

minus :: CalcParser (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
minus = do
    char '-'    
    return (-)  

multiply :: CalcParser Integer
multiply = do
    spaces
    lhv <- enclosed
    spaces
    t <- many tail
    return $ applyMany lhv t
    where tail =
                do
                    f <- star <|> div_
                    spaces
                    rhv <- enclosed
                    spaces
                    return (`f` rhv)


add :: CalcParser Integer
add = do
    spaces
    lhv <- multiply <|> fact' <|> negation'
    spaces
    t <- many tail
    return $ applyMany lhv t
    where tail =
                do
                    f <- plus <|> minus
                    spaces
                    rhv <- multiply <|> fact' <|> negation'
                    spaces
                    return (`f` rhv)

enclosed :: CalcParser Integer
enclosed = number <|> do
    char '('
    res <- add
    char ')'
    return res

-- factorial    
fact' :: CalcParser Integer
fact' = do
    spaces
    char '!'
    rhv <- number
    return $ factorial rhv  

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n
    | n < 0 = error "No factorial exists for negative inputs" 
    | n == 0 || n == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = acc n 1
    where
    acc 0 a = a
    acc b a = acc (b-1) (b * a)  

-- negation 
negation' :: CalcParser Integer
negation' = do
    spaces
    char '~'
    rhv <- enclosed
    spaces
    return $ negate rhv
```

Listing above includes function definitions for primary operations extended with negation and factorial calculation options. What I need, it's just to make this program sensitive to floating point values as well as to integers in any string input. How could I implement that to start parser by calling an only function (applicable to both Fractional and Integral numbers) as follows (just for example):

```
parseTest totalCalc "~(8.44 * 12.85 / 3.2) * !4"
```

I input '!' character in prior to a numeric part of factorial notation, because parser doesn't appear to recognize normal '4!' or similar character sequences as factorial indicators.

Comment: Instead of trying to support both integers and floating point side-by-side, simply change it to support floating point exclusively. Integers are a subset of Doubles (for integers less than 2^52 in magnitude) so this doesn't stop you from calculating `1+2`

Comment: Your parser is insisting on "!4" instead of "4!" because that is what it says. Look at `fact'`. It first parses the "!" and then parses the number. Try swapping them.

Comment: @Paul Johnson, thank you, your note is sane. However, I first (ahead of posting this question) tried to parse "4!" putting `char '.'` under `rhv <- number`. It resulted into this case: instead of factorial computing on test input `parseTest addition "3 + 7 + 4!"` (expected 34), outcome was 14, just as if "!" to be completely ignored or oddly forced off once a number occurred. Following that, I decided to use mark precedence notation. Fairly, I'm curious to see clear what causes such a strange shrinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** search+replace all occurrences of `Integer` to `Double`. Now your parser still can only read integers, but internally it will represent them as `Double`s.

**Step 2:** make the `number` parser parse either a whole number or a floating-point one. The whole number you already got down: it's just a sequence of digits. Let's rename it to better reflect what it's doing:

```
parseInt :: CalcParser Double
parseInt = read <$> many1 digit
```

The floating-point is not much more difficult: it's a sequence of digits, followed by a dot (period), followed by another sequence of digits:

```
parseDouble :: CalcParser Double
parseDouble = do
    whole <- many1 digit
    char '.'
    fract <- many1 digit
    pure $ read $ whole <> "." <> fract
```

And then *any* number would just be "either double or int":

```
number :: CalcParser Double
number = try parseDouble <|> parseInt
```

Two more notes:

**First**, note that you have to try the double first. If you don't, the string `"8.32"` will be parsed as an int, because the prefix `"8"` matches the rules for `parseInt`.

**Second**, note that you have to use `try` with `parseDouble`. If you don't, whole numbers will fail to parse, because the `parseDouble` parser will consume the input up to the end of the digits, won't see a dot, will fail, but *will not roll back to the beginning of the digits*, so that `parseInt` will not see any digits and will fail too. The `try` combinator is what does the roll back to the start when the parser fails.

Comment: `try parseDouble <|> parseInt` is a convenient way to write a parser, but it also adds significant overhead and makes it harder to generate useful error messages. A non-homework version of this would avoid having to backtrack and re-read the number as an integer by parsing a number followed by an optional fractional part

Comment: Well, I prioritized the ease of explanation over efficiency

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, absolutely, your explanatory approach is very robust to catch on this matter, many thanks. Now I see clear what and why to be done, pretty nice response.